# How to create Azure Alerts using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, monitoring, azure-monitoring

I need to create alerts for multiple vms using terraform. Has someone got a simple example I could use , for example :

I want to monitor azure virtual machines called vm01, vm01, vm03 in Resource Group called Rg1. I want to monitor CPU usage and Memory for example.
Can someone help with a simple example I can then build on ?

Comment: Is there anything you already tried that's not working? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_metric_alert

Answer (score 10):

You can try this:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "example-rg"
  location = "northeurope"
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "ag" {
  name                = "myactiongroup"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  short_name          = "exampleactiongroup"

}

resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "alert" {
  name                = "example-metricalert"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  scopes              = ["/subscriptions/1234xxx"]
  description         = "description"
  target_resource_type = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
  
  criteria { 
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
    metric_name      = "Percentage CPU"
    aggregation      = "Total"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 80
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.ag.id
  }
}
```

Terraform provider doc for Azure alerts is [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_metric_alert)

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers.

Comment: you also need an Alert Processing Rule nowadays - or no alert is sent